Grapes of Wrath passage meaning: 'go down the line'
I have a question about a couple of sentences from this passage in Grapes of Wrath, after Tom and Al are driving to a town as they make their way to California:

"Well, look, Tom. I got six dollars. You an' me could get a couple pints an' go down
the line. Nobody don't know I got that six bucks. Christ, we could have a hell of a time
for ourselves."
"Keep ya jack," Tom said. "When we get out to the coast you an' me'll take her an'
we'll raise hell. Maybe when we're workin'—" He turned in the seat. "I didn' think you was a fella to go down the line. I figgered you was talkin' 'em out of it."
"Well, hell, I don't know nobody here. If I'm gonna ride aroun' much, I'm gonna get
married. I'm gonna have me a hell of a time when we get to California."

Basically I'm confused about what it means to "go down the line". I'm assuming it has something to do with prostitution, but that makes me confused about the line "If I'm gonna ride aroun' much, I'm gonna get married." Is this said sarcastically? If not, what could this mean? I thought "riding around" literally meant driving, but does he mean something sexual?

It might be better to ask this in [literature.se].

@Barmar Didn't know that was a possibility, thanks!

The meaning of "down the line" in this instance appears to be the first definition of the term given in Harold Wentworth & Stuart Flexner, American Slang Dictionary (1960):

down the line 1 In the district of a city that contains brothels, cheap bars, or the like. 2 To go from one person to another, in descending order of their importance, or authority, as in asking for a favor, seeking information, or the like.

J.E. Lighter, Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang (1997) has fuller coverage of pre-Depression instances of the term:

go down the line to go carousing in a red-light district. 1905 Nat[ional] Police Gaz[ette] (Dec. 9) 3: It may be that you...don't know what it means to go "down the line." 1908 W.G. Davenport Butte & Montana 263: He has evidently been up and down the line. 1910 Hapgood City Streets 59: He...treats all his friends as he goes "down the line." 1916 Cary Venery I 112: *Going Down the Line—To go whore hopping. 1929 Milburn Hornbook 193 {ref. to ca1900}: I took a a stroll along the "line"; "set up" for all the boys. ...

On the other hand, Maurice Weseen, Dictionary of American Slang (1934) has this entry in the section on "Hoboes' and Tramps' Slang":

Go down the line—To be discharged from a job.

And Hyman Goldin, Dictionary of American Underworld Slang (1950) reports that "go down the line for" is equivalent to "go to bat [for]":

Go to bat. 1, To fight, finance, or otherwise give another one's full support. (Usually followed by the preposition "for.") 2. To stand trial in criminal proceedings.

It seems pretty clear to me that meaning #1 of "down the line" in Wentworth & Flexner and the only meaning of "go down the line" in Lighter express the intended sense of the term as used by the Okie migrants in The Grapes of Wrath (published in 1939).

How does this square with the later sentence "If I'm gonna ride aroun' much, I'm gonna get married." It's presented seemingly as part of a rationale for going "down the line" by a person who otherwise might not. -- Getting married and visiting the red light district seems to be at odds.

@R.M.: The only way it makes (partial) sense to me is that Al is saying that he plans to gather rosebuds while he may—that is, have a wild time before he gets pinned down to the serious responsibilities of a married man. I don't know, however, what to make of the assertion "If I'm gonna ride aroun' much, I'm gonna get married." The sense of that statement seems to hinge on what he means by "ride around," and I don't whether his intended meaning is literal or figurative and, if the latter, what "ride around" is referring to. Maybe he is just comparing being on the road to living on a farm.

@SvenYargs After thinking about your comment, I do think it seems to be that Al is saying that he's ultimately the type to wind up getting married due to his womanizing, and is taking the opportunity of spending a night in a town he doesn't know and will never visit again to do away with the romance and just focus on physical pleasure. I'm thinking it's possible that Al is referencing life in California, rather than the journey there, when he talks about "riding around" and getting married. Would appreciate any other possible explanations, though, in case I am misunderstanding the meaning.
